# Admin: Remove user from group

Tags: django

I was wondering how you can remove a user from a group in the admin. Seems I can add them to a group fine but if you only have one group it seems you can't deselect it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+click to deselect the last item.

BTW, that's the same key combo used to select multiple items in a `<select>` box with multiple selection enabled.